# Pagination in Wizard Redux Form in Stateless Component

Tags: forms, redux, state, stateless

i'm new to react-redux and i want some help with a task. As you can see in the redux-form documentation for a wizard for the author uses a stateful main component to create next and previous page functions using setState but in our project we must not use class base components

```
class WizardForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this)
    this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      page: 1
    }
  }
  nextPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 })
  }

  previousPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page - 1 })
  }

  render() {
    const { onSubmit } = this.props
    const { page } = this.state
    return (<div>
        {page === 1 && <WizardFormFirstPage onSubmit={this.nextPage}/>}
        {page === 2 && <WizardFormSecondPage previousPage={this.previousPage} onSubmit={this.nextPage}/>}
        {page === 3 && <WizardFormThirdPage previousPage={this.previousPage} onSubmit={onSubmit}/>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

How to make this transformation correctly?

Comment: Not using class-based components seems kind of arbitrary, but two options would be 1) store the current page in the URL, and change it with the router 2) store the current page in the Redux store, and change it with an action.

Comment: I use the first option you provide, but it doesn't seem right to me....i'l try the second! Thanks :)

Comment: By using the routing, i use a Link to the next button for example. The page is changing but the submit action didnt work. When i avoid link the submit action worked properly